# Parsing XML in java (javax.xml.bind.annotation)

Tags: java, xml

I'd like to parse this xml file into java class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MESSAGE>Sample of FreeText
  <DAY>
   ...........
  </DAY>
</MESSAGE>
```

using javax.xml.bind.annotation i have made this converted class:

```
@XmlRootElement( name  = "MESSAGE" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ReceivedInfo implements Serializable{

@XmlElement( name = "DAY" )
private List<ReceivedBaseDayInfo> diaList;
```

used in the class that transofrms it:

```
public static Object transformXMLStringToJava(String xmlString, Class<?> baseClass) throws Exception
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(baseClass);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
}
```

Everything works ok unless parsing 'Sample of FreeText' text.
How should be defined this freetext int java class to be parsed?
Regards!

Comment: Try adding a new field to ReceivedInfo annotated as @XmlValue.

Comment: Adding @XMLValue returned me an execution error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have fixed adding this the property:

```
@XmlMixed
private List<String >  freeText;

@XmlElement( name = "DAY" )
private List<ReceivedBaseDayInfo> diaList;
```